# not able to call restfull services

Tags: rest, restful-url

I am learning restfull , I have downloaded and deployed the example from following url.

http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-jpa-data-hibernate-mysql/   U can download source from git hub in page link

I have deployed and its deployed without an error.

When i am calling this restfull it is showing 404. I am using following url to call service.

```
  http://127.0.0.1:8080/dpr-data/shop/create
```

Am i doing some thing wrong.

Can any body look into this example . I have moved spring configuration from java class to xml .

```
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.spr.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spr.exception" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spr.init" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spr.model" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spr.repository" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spr.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spr.validation" />

<bean id="transactionManager"   class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="medical-unit" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="/WEB-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="dss.hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="dss.hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
            <prop key="dss.hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">true</prop>
            <prop key="dss.hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="dss.hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="dss.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="dss.hibernate.connection.username">root</prop>
            <prop key="dss.hibernate.connection.password">root</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/medicalstore" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>


<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" >
          <property name="prefix">
             <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
          </property>
          <property name="suffix">
             <value>.jsp</value>
          </property>
          <property name="viewClass">
             <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value>
          </property>

    </bean>

<!-- Data Source Declaration 
<bean id="commonBasePooledDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">

</bean>-->
```

Deploy works perfectly and controller is getting initiated , I am have put one log in @postconstructor methos and log is printing. But i am not able to get result from this service.

Comment: Have you checked the server log for any exceptions when the service is deployed?

Comment: there is no exception in logs

Answer (score 0):

Having looked at the example, I noticed that the final name defined for the project in the POM is:

```
<finalName>dpr-data</finalName>
```

Note, starts with a 'd', not 's'.

This will result in the war file dpr-data.war and will be deployed to the context root *dpr-data*. This means you should access the service using the following URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/dpr-data/shop/create
```

Comment: Yes , I am using dpr-data , but result in not populating :(

Comment: Your original post states you are using the context root spr-data

Comment: Sorry , that was my typing mistake :(

Comment: I test it with following method @PostConstruct public void test() { System.out.println("on the way"); try { shopService.delete(1); } catch (ShopNotFound e) { System.out.println("error in deleting"); e.printStackTrace(); } } postconstruct is deleting data , there is some issue in calling service

Comment: So the test() method is working? Is deleting data? If so, what is the issue you are referring to?

Comment: it is working because it is in the @postconstruct of the controller. While server getting started , controller instance is created and post constructor is get called , and its deleting the data. But when i am calling using webbrowser non of any method is working.

Comment: Could you post the relevant part of your application server log as it starts up.